# Reposition vertices at the origin of a coordinate system

Tags: java, performance, beginner, coordinate-system

This method repositions vertices of an object in such a way that the center of the object is at the origin of the coordinate system. The task is the commented part. While my code does the job I feel that it is very basic. I am looking for advice on how to make it faster and more elegant, concise and efficient. Any comments are welcome.

```
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

public class ObjModifier {
    public static void centerVertices(FloatBuffer buf) {
        // We often get 3D models which are not positioned at the origin of the coordinate system. Placing such models
        // on a 3D map is harder for users. One solution is to reposition such a model so that its center is at the
        // origin of the coordinate system. Your task is to implement the centering.
        //
        // FloatBuffer stores the vertices of a mesh in a continuous array of floats (see below)
        // [x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1, ..., xn, yn, zn]
        // This kind of layout is common in low-level 3D graphics APIs.
        // TODO: Implement your solution here

        float[] a = new float[buf.capacity()];
        buf.get(a);

        float[] sums = new float[3];
        float[] avgs = new float[3];

        for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length; i+=3) {
            sums[0] += a[i];
            sums[1] += a[i+1];
            sums[2] += a[i+2];           

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < avgs.length; i++) {
            avgs[i] = sums[i]/(a.length/3);
        }

        for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length; i+=3) {
            a[i] -= avgs[0];
            a[i+1] -= avgs[1];
            a[i+2] -= avgs[2];         

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            buf.put(i, a[i]);
        }
        //

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a separate method for calculating averages and use variables for them, so that the code is more legible.

I don't personally like the use of arrays such as `sum[]` and `avg[]` because looping over them makes it hard to tell what you are trying to access. If you do want to use them, I would save their indices (or offsets) in static final fields so that the accesses looks like this:

```
    sum[i + X_OFFSET] = ...;
    sum[i + Y_OFFSET] = ...;
    sum[i + Z_OFFSET] = ...;
```

I used the stream API for convenience - a loop would be fine too.

````
private static final int X_OFFSET = 0;
private static final int Y_OFFSET = 1;
private static final int Z_OFFSET = 2;

public static void centerVertices(FloatBuffer buf) {

    float[] objVertices = new float[buf.capacity()];
    buf.get(objVertices);

    float xAvg = (float) getAverage(objVertices, X_OFFSET);
    float yAvg = (float) getAverage(objVertices, Y_OFFSET);
    float zAvg = (float) getAverage(objVertices, Z_OFFSET);

    for (int i = 0; i < objVertices.length; i += 3) {
        objVertices[i + X_OFFSET] -= xAvg;
        objVertices[i + Y_OFFSET] -= yAvg;
        objVertices[i + Z_OFFSET] -= zAvg;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < objVertices.length; i++) {
        buf.put(i, objVertices[i]);
    }
}

/**
 * Get the average of every third element in the array (with offset)
 */
private static double getAverage(float[] arr, int offset) {
    return IntStream //
            .range(0, arr.length) //
            .filter(i -> i % 3 == offset) //
            .mapToDouble(i -> arr[i]).average() //
            .getAsDouble();
}
```
````

Answer (score 2):

Hello, you can store the value `a.length` in a variable and reuse it in all your loops.

```
int n = a.length;
```

You can rewrite the first loop of your code introducing a new index k for the array `sums` in this way:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < n; i+=3) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k) {
        sums[k] += a[i + k];
    }
}
```

Similarly, you can rewrite the second loop:

```
int d = n / 3;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    avgs[i] = sums[i] / d;
}
```

The third one is similar to the first one:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < n; i+=3) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k) {
        a[i + k] -= avgs[k];
    }
}
```

In the forth one, you can substitute `a.length` with `n`.

Comment: thank you. is there a reason to use ++k instead of k++?

Comment: @JanPisl: you can use pre-increment or post-increment operator in a loop and you will obtain the same result, but usually the preincrement opeator is preferred. If you read the thread at  the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706199/post-increment-and-pre-increment-within-a-for-loop-produce-same-output there is the full explanation of why it is preferred to use preincrement over postincrement operator and a lot of debates about it.